# Ractive.js: Animation was not found

Tags: javascript, jquery, mustache, ractivejs

Initially I thought this problem was related to my Gulp setup, but I think there's something else here.

My transition plugins load fine initially, but after I load a partial into the template and back out of it, Ractive can't find the animation plugin. Ractive is being loaded prior to the plugins, as it should be. Anyone run into this?

Comment: This is possibly a case of Ractive being over-eager with debugging messages - I've raised an [issue](https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/issues/1755) to look into it. I encounter this message when I'm doing a lot of animations that override previous animations - as far as I can tell (not a totally satisfactory answer since I'm the one who added that message, albeit many moons ago) the message by itself doesn't indicate anything wrong. Unless you're experience unexpected behaviour - visual glitches or similar?

Comment: Yes, there are glitches. 

So I have my primary template, a partial loads with a fade based on user input. If the user programmatically backs up out of that partial and returns, the animation fails and the data that should show up via the animation no longer displays.

Unless I misunderstanding the transitions plugin purpose and it isn't meant to work on individual elements inside a partial, just the template itself.

As an aside, I love this library. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Thanks! Any chance you could put reproduce the bug in a JSFiddle or equivalent? (Here's a [starter template](http://jsfiddle.net/rich_harris/va6jU/)). Without a reproduction I can't be sure what's going on. Feel free to [raise an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/issues) if necessary

Comment: Well, I'm an idiot. I was calling a reset() on the data in the form, wherein the elements to be animated were residing. I'm upvoting the last comment because, at the very least, walking through it on jsfiddle helped me realize what I was doing. 

As an aside, is there a way to reset specific components of the data object, and leave others as they are? Right now, I have to declare certain things inside my Reactive data definition and again in the reset() call.

Comment: When you say 'reset specific components', do you mean actually deleting them? We're considering adding a `ractive.unset()` method ([issue here](https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/issues/1649)), though I've always found `ractive.set('foo.bar.baz', null)` does the trick

Comment: Not deleting, returning to a 'default' state. For example, I have a data object - 

    data: {
        items: ['a','b','c'],
        elementWithDefaultValue:true, // default: false
        userEntry:'Bob'
     }

If I do ractive.reset() right now, either elementWithDefaultValue goes null or I have to do ractive.reset({elementWithDefaultValue:true}). Which for one element isn't bad, but for many elements is a lot of WET code.

Comment: Hmm. When you say it has a default value, you mean on the prototype? Might be easier to discuss this on GitHub

Comment: Done. Thanks! https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/issues/1760